# Using a groovy script *file* in an elasticsearch query - groovy script file location

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I'm trying to reference a groovy script file that I created, and getting unable to find (see below).  I didn't have a config directory, and elasticsearch.yml is in etc/elasticsearch.  I added config/scripts/ under usr/share/elasticsearch so I now have /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/scripts/.

In there, I placed my script- 'source_types.groovy', which I ran chown elasticsearch:elasticsearch on to ensure the user called elasticsearch owns it.

I also put a config/scripts/source_types.groovy in etc/elasticsearch.

I am trying to call the script as follows:

```
GET nr-01/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "file": "source_types.groovy",
          "lang": "groovy"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm getting

```
nested: SearchParseException[[nr-01][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n  \"query\": {\n    \"filtered\": {\n      \"filter\": {\n        \"script\": {\n          \"file\": \"source_types.groovy\",\n          \"lang\": \"groovy\"\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n]]]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Unable to find on disk script source_types.groovy]; }]",
   "status": 400
```

Obviously the file can't be found.  Where does the script go?  Am I calling it correctly?

Comment: If you remove the extension from the name of the file, like `"file": "source_types"`, do you see any difference?

Comment: Also, try putting your *.groovy files under `/etc/elasticsearch/scripts` folder (meaning omitting `config`).

Comment: @AndreiStefan I just figured out that the scripts should be under /etc/elasticsearch/scripts folder as you suggested.  I came back to answer my question but since you answered it, if you put it as an answer, I'll mark it correct.  thanks.  BTW I'm gonna put in another related question so be on the lookout!  thx! :-)

Comment: Wow - annoying - I wanted to post a different question to avoid adding to this one because really this one is answer but I'm told by stack overflow that I can only post once in 90 minutes.  that's a long time to wait for a follow-up question!

I'm getting responses from 2 out of 3 nodes in the cluster but the file isn't being found on the 3rd node, but it's on all nodes with same name and permissions!

Comment: So, you have the exact file on all three nodes in the same location, but you get responses only from two nodes?

Comment: yep!  I'm going to make a separate issue tho because it really is separate.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927384/cant-find-groovy-script-file-on-one-out-of-3-nodes-elasticsearch-groovy-script

Answer (score 2):

Put your `*.groovy` files under `/etc/elasticsearch/scripts` folder (meaning omitting `config`).