# can't find groovy script file on one out of 3 nodes. elasticsearch groovy script in a file

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I'm getting responses from 2 out of 3 nodes in the cluster.

[Using a groovy script *file* in an elasticsearch query - groovy script file location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908264/using-a-groovy-script-file-in-an-elasticsearch-query-groovy-script-file-loca)

The file isn't being found on the 3rd node, but it's on all nodes with same name and permissions!

Nodes are named demo01 - 03.

Here's some log output:

```
demo03:
    [2015-06-18 05:52:21,739][INFO ][script                   ] [demo03] removing script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/source_types.groovy]
    [2015-06-18 06:40:16,764][INFO ][script                   ] [demo03] compiling script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/source_types.groovy]
    [2015-06-18 06:40:41,771][INFO ][script                   ] [demo03] compiling script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/source_types.groovy]
    [2015-06-18 06:41:06,779][INFO ][script                   ] [demo03] compiling script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/source_types.groovy]
    [2015-06-18 06:44:26,788][INFO ][script                   ] [demo03] removing script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/source_types.groovy~]
    [2015-06-18 06:47:21,789][INFO ][script                   ] [demo03] compiling script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/source_types.groovy]
    [2015-06-18 06:47:21,798][WARN ][script                   ] [demo03] no script engine found for [groovy~]
    [2015-06-18 06:49:51,799][INFO ][script                   ] [demo03] removing script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/source_types.groovy~]
demo02:
    [2015-06-18 05:52:18,078][INFO ][script                   ] [demo02] removing script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/source_types.groovy]
    [2015-06-18 06:41:03,098][INFO ][script                   ] [demo02] compiling script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/source_types.groovy]
    [2015-06-18 06:46:28,109][INFO ][script                   ] [demo02] compiling script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/source_types.groovy]
```

Comment: Are you certain your file is named properly, I see `source_types.groovy~`, i.e. with a `~` at the end. Can you make sure the extension is `groovy` and not `groovy~`?

Comment: yes, it was the name I expected, without the ~.  I don't know what those were.

Comment: file names with tilde at the end are usually backup files from vim or emacs. maybe that's why.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the file and recreated it, and the search works now.  I don't know the root cause.